# How to send a parameter rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I know this is kinda silly.
Anyways,I want to implement a test coupon system.In which if a user enters a coupon, the corresponding amount of money for that coupon in the database, will be added to that particular user's account. 

I have my coupons controller as

```
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
def redeem
    @coupon = Coupon.find_by_code(params[:code])
    if (@coupon.number_avail!=0)
      current_user.account = current_user.account + @coupon.amount
    else 
      flash[:notice] = "Coupon Invalid!"
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

And my routes file as :

```
get '/coupon/redeem' => 'coupons#redeem'
```

Everything works fine doing manually likes site/coupon/redeem?code=test; This works good. But I want to take the input from the user and pass the paramater.

How can I arrange in such a way that there is a form and a user can enter the coupon code and pass that to coupons#redeem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity just add a

```
     redeem.html.erb   # in app/views/coupons
     #add this kind of code
      <form method="post" action="redeem" >
     <input type="text" value="" size="" name="coupon[yourchoice]" id="coupon_yourchoice">
        <%= button_to "submit" ,:action => "redeem" %>
      </form>

        #in your app/controller/coupon
           def redeem
             @variable = params
             puts @variable.inspect # to see the content
           end



    #for posting parameters to different url

     step :1  change the action of the form something like this,
     action="/yourchoice/abc"

         step :2  make changes in config/route.rb
       match '/yourchoice/abc', :to => 'yourcontroller#action', :via => [:get ,:post]

    step : 3  make an action in  yourcontroller
       def action
          @var = params
          p @var   #check the variable
       end
```

Comment: Thanks It works. But Did some modifications in the controllers :)

Comment: hey, what if i want to send to a particular url ? Thanks.

Comment: @pbssubhash :check the above solution i have updated it 
#for posting parameters to different url

Answer (score 2):

Err this seems rather basic.

```
<% form_tag redeem_coupons_path do %>
  <label>Coupon <%= text_field_tag "code" %></label>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Note that this form will use a POST request, which is the appropriate method for this action.  You should change your routes to make it expect a POST not a GET for this.

EDIT: also, your controller code needs to account for the possibility of not finding a coupon for that code.  I would change it to this:

```
def redeem
  if (@coupon = Coupon.find_by_code(params[:code])) && (@coupon.number_avail != 0)
    current_user.account = current_user.account + @coupon.amount
  else 
    flash[:notice] = "Coupon Invalid!"
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

Comment: Screen shows nothing. I mean, there isn't any form visible.. Err.. I know it's pretty simple. I've just started in rails. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I think you need to work through some more tutorials or something.  The only reason that form wouldn't be visible is if it's not actually being rendered out at all.

Comment: Haha, yup. As I said I'm still learning. I eventually figured it out. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Upvoting your answer, as I eventually figured out the work flow.

Comment: @MaxWilliams shouldn't it be `<%= form_tag` instead of `<% form_tag`?

Comment: @art-solopov actually yes, in modern versions of rails it needs the `<%=` rather than just `<%`

Answer (score 1):

The right way would be to use the standard [resourceful routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :coupons, only: [], param: :code do
   match :redeem, via: [:get, :post], on: :member #-> url.com/coupons/:code/redeem
end

#app/controllers/coupons_controller.rb
class CouponsController < ApplicationController
   def redeem
      @coupon = Coupon.find params[:code]
      if (@coupon.number_avail!=0)
         current_user.increment!(:account, @coupon.amount)
      else 
         redirect_to root_path, notice: "Coupon Invalid!"
      end
   end 
end
```

This would allow you to use:

```
<%= button_to @coupon.value, coupon_redeem_path(@coupon) %>
```

--

If you wanted the user to specify the coupon code itself, you'd be able to retain the `routes` and `controller#action` as above, except with a different input:

```
<%= form_for coupon_redeem_path do %>
   <%= text_field_tag :code %>
   <%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

---

If you don't want to reveal the `:coupon_id`, you should use a `POST` request:

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :coupons, only: [], param: :code do
   post :redeem, on: :collection #-> url.com/coupons/redeem
end
```

The [difference between `GET` and `POST`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) is that...

> In a POST request, the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the HTTP message body
>
> In a GET request, the query string (name/value pairs) is sent in the URL

Comment: Your solution works but I prefer not to reveal coupon_id in the URL or elsewhere to the user due to some reasons. Thanks for helping!

Comment: And also, In the code, @coupon.save and current_user.save must be there because without it, it won't be updated inside the database.. Just figured it now..

Comment: Yup, I know the difference between get and post, but I just wanted to expose coupon code and nothing else. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem, didn't mean to insult your intelligence. Hope you have a great day!

Comment: Haha, I understand :) thanks for taking out your time to help me! Hope you'll have a great day too.